# 0 before the number

Tags: ruby, integer

i want print it in this format: 
ex.

```
1 -> 000001
15 -> 000015
```

How can i do?
thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sprintf "%06d", 1     #=> "000001"
sprintf "%06d", 15    #=> "000015"
```

or more briefly

```
"%06d" % 1     #=> "000001"
"%06d" % 15    #=> "000015"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 "#{1}".rjust(6,'0') # => 000001
"#{15}".rjust(6,'0') # => 000015
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005962), or string formatting (`%`) like so:

```
>> "%06d" % 1
=> "000001"
>> "%06d" % 15
=> "000015"
```